# Purpose of the term property

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-edu

What is the purpose of the term property in the educationClass?

```
PATCH
https://graph.microsoft.com/V1.0/education/classes/4fbd34af-a6f7-4e27-90a7-5512e3dd64a4
```

With body

```
{
  "@odata.context":"https://graph.microsoft.com/V1.0/$metadata#education/classes/$entity",
  "description":"Mijn 2e test",
  "displayName":"Mijn 2e test",
  "mailNickname":"Team_9332",
  "id":"4fbd34af-a6f7-4e27-90a7-5512e3dd64a4",
  "externalSource":"sis",
  "externalId":"9332",
  "createdBy":
  {
    "application":
    {
      "id":"0a88941d-f499-43ed-a61e-5400ea986852"
    }
,
    "user":
    {
      "id":"b1b24649-7d77-40a3-8158-bbb0ce890ee7"
    }
  }
,
  "term":
  {
    "startDate":"2019-05-01",
    "endDate":"2019-05-30"
  }
}
```

In the teams application I do not see any difference between education teams where the term property is set or not.

I thought that, in an earlier version, if you entered the startDate and endDate  of the term property, it was not possible to create any assignments before or after these dates.

Answer (score 1):

Right now, it's a pure data holder, that can be synced into the API using our School Data Sync product from a back end SIS/MIS system in a school or manipulated as you're doing.

None of our built-in experiences is being guided by the data in there AFAIK.